# Return HTTP Status and JSON response C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a REST API and I when there is validation message, I want to return an HTTP status of 400 along with the list of validation messages. For example, in Postman I want the status in the tool to show a 400 and in response body show the JSON list of messages.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromBody] ServiceRequest serviceRequest)
{
    try
    {
        var user = User.FindFirst("client_id")?.Value;
        int VendorId = await _audit.Log(user, AuditLogClass.API_READ, "serviceData");

        List<string> ValidationMessages = _serviceRequestBO.processServiceRequest(serviceRequest);

        if (ValidationMessages.Count == 0)
        {
            await _emailService.SendEmailAsync("mark.walker@magenium.com", "Success", "Service Request created");                  
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
        }
        else
        {
            //StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest
            return new JsonResult(ValidationMessages);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "serviceData - GET");
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC? ASP.NET Web API? Or ASP.NET Core? Please tag your question appropriately to help answerers know what framework you're in and help attract the people knowledgeable about the framework to your question.

Comment: just do `return BadRequest(validationMessages);` and `return Ok();`.

Comment: Simply use BadRequest() and pass the custom message in that

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is ASP.NET Core MVC, the `JsonResult` class has `StatusCode` property. So

```
...
return new JsonResult(ValidationMessages)
{
    StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest
};
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use this the BadRequest() overload described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-2.2#System_Web_Http_ApiController_BadRequest_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ModelBinding_ModelStateDictionary_).